# Why does my computer repeatedly query a non-existent SRV record when I open "AD Users and Computers"?

Tags: active-directory

I have replaced my domain with `example.com`. I have 3 domain controllers: `FARORE` (primary), `NAYRU`, and `DIN`. The site name is `DataCenter`. In the course of trying to figure out why "AD Users and Computers" is unusable slow when accessed over the VPN I noticed these messages in wireshark:

```
No such name SRV _ldap._tcp.DIN.example.com SOA DIN.example.com
No such name SRV _ldap._tcp.DataCenter._sites.DIN.example.com SOA nayru.example.com
```

On my desktop at work it queries the domains in this order

- `_ldap._tcp.DataCenter._sites.DIN.example.com` (fails)
- `_ldap._tcp.DIN.example.com` (fails)
- `_ldap._tcp.DataCenter._sites.dc._msdcs.example.com` (returns an SRV record)

On my laptop on the VPN it just queries the first two over and over. I have tested via nslookup that I can query the same SRV record at `_ldap._tcp.DataCenter._sites.dc._msdcs.example.com` from my laptop.

I'm mostly telling you about the VPN thing for background. My main question is: what are the two records ending in `DIN.example.com`? Should they exist? If not, why does AD Users and Computers query for them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All these queries are related to [Locating a Domain Controller](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/3e9711af-9067-435e-93fb-09182053cef7) with [DNS-Based Discovery](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/7fcdce70-5205-44d6-9c3a-260e616a2f04), and there's even quite some more variations documented. In short, in the first two records a client tries to locate a *LDAP server*, and in the third a *domain controller* (DC).

Something might still be wrong, as normally *naming context* in these queries is still `example.com` instead of `DCNAME.example.com`, whereas you have the following (it's normal that the first two don't exist):

- `_ldap._tcp.DataCenter._sites.DIN.example.com`

  - `DIN.example.com` is the *naming context* `N` and
  - `DataCenter` is the *site name* `Y` in

  > To locate an [LDAP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/b645c125-a7da-4097-84a1-2fa7cea07714#gt_45643bfb-b4c4-432c-a10f-b98790063f8d) server hosting [NC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/b645c125-a7da-4097-84a1-2fa7cea07714#gt_784c7cce-f782-48d8-9444-c9030ba86942) `N` in [site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/b645c125-a7da-4097-84a1-2fa7cea07714#gt_8abdc986-5679-42d9-ad76-b11eb5a0daba) `Y`, the client machine
  > issues a DNS query for the [SRV record](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/b645c125-a7da-4097-84a1-2fa7cea07714#gt_c24d4432-389e-41ba-b00b-f565ac0aae0f) `_ldap._tcp.Y._sites.N`,
  > constructed from the NC name (`N`) and the site name (`Y`).
- `_ldap._tcp.DIN.example.com`; `DIN.example.com` = `N` in

  > To locate an [LDAP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/b645c125-a7da-4097-84a1-2fa7cea07714#gt_45643bfb-b4c4-432c-a10f-b98790063f8d) server hosting [NC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/b645c125-a7da-4097-84a1-2fa7cea07714#gt_784c7cce-f782-48d8-9444-c9030ba86942) `N`, the client machine issues a DNS
  > query for the [SRV record](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/b645c125-a7da-4097-84a1-2fa7cea07714#gt_c24d4432-389e-41ba-b00b-f565ac0aae0f) `_ldap._tcp.N`, constructed from the NC name
  > (`N`).
- `_ldap._tcp.DataCenter._sites.dc._msdcs.example.com`

  - `example.com` is the *naming context* `N` and
  - `DataCenter` is the *site name* `Y` in

  > To locate a [DC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/b645c125-a7da-4097-84a1-2fa7cea07714#gt_76a05049-3531-4abd-aec8-30e19954b4bd) hosting [NC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/b645c125-a7da-4097-84a1-2fa7cea07714#gt_784c7cce-f782-48d8-9444-c9030ba86942) `N` in [site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/b645c125-a7da-4097-84a1-2fa7cea07714#gt_8abdc986-5679-42d9-ad76-b11eb5a0daba) `Y`, the client machine issues a DNS
  > query for the [SRV record](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/b645c125-a7da-4097-84a1-2fa7cea07714#gt_c24d4432-389e-41ba-b00b-f565ac0aae0f) `_ldap._tcp.Y._sites.dc._msdcs.N`, constructed
  > from the NC name (`N`) and the site name (`Y`).

To debug this discovery process, reading Mitchell Grande's [Domain Controller Selection](https://www.concurrency.com/blog/may-2018/domain-controller-selection) could be a good start, and it also introduces some helpful commands:

> - `echo %logonserver%` - This shows the DC that was used to authenticate and log in the current user
> - `nltest /dsgetsite` - This shows the AD site that the current server has detected that it's in
> - `nltest /dclist:` (include the colon at the end) - This shows the list of DCs in the current domain, including which site each is in.

To address the slowness of the AD administration tools over VPN I'd suggest:

- Check that the VPN subnet is added to the nearest site in *AD Sites and Services*.
- I've experienced similar problems when someone had an OpenVPN client from an UTM appliance in use. It happened to be that this client was using an older OpenVPN TAP adapter driver, and replacing it with recent [OpenVPN Connect](https://openvpn.net/download-open-vpn/) solved this issue (among others).